# Issue with ZF2 Navigation

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a module named Member and have two controllers in it Member and Registration.

I need a menu which will be like "View Member" -> "Edit Member" and "Become a member" links.

The routes are as under :

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'member' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/member[/:action]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Member\Controller\Member',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'registration' => array(
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/registration[/:action]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),  
            ),
        ),
        'registration' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/registration[/:action]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Member\Controller\Registration',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

The Navigation code is :

```
'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Home',
            'route' => 'home',
            'type' => 'Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Member', // 'Page #1',
            'route' => 'member', // 'page-1',
            'action'     => 'index',
            'resource'  => 'Member\Controller\Member',
            'pages' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Edit', // 'Child #1',
                    'route' => 'member',
                    'params' => array('action' => 'memberEdit'),
                    'resource'  => 'Member\Controller\Member',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'Become a member',
            'route' => 'registration',
            'controller' => 'registration',
            'action' => 'index',
            'resource' => 'Member\Controller\Registration',
        ),
    ),
),
```

The service manager is :

```
    'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
    ),
),
```

The layout code is :

```
$this->navigation('navigation')
                                ->menu()
                                ->setMinDepth(0)
                                ->setMaxDepth(1)
                                ->setUlClass('nav navbar-nav');
```

All links work except the "Become a member" link. When you click on it gives an error message

```
Route with name "default" not found
```

Please help.

Comment: According to the route being checked for a match, it is always top to bottom. If it gets a match then it won't go further for checking it. In your code, the `registration` can be a child route under `member` and also a separate route. So just write the `registration` route above (before) the `member` route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the routes -

`'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'registration' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/registration[/:action]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Member\Controller\Registration',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'member' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/member[/:action]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Member\Controller\Member',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'registration' => array(
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/registration[/:action]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),

            ),
        ),
    ),
),`

This way you can use both `registration` and `member/registration` routes.

I hope it helps.